I want to store the state of my webview so that i can directly reach to my previous session if not then load from scracth
class TempFragment: Fragment() {

private val urls=listOf("https://stackoverflow.com","https://www.youtube.com","https://www.flipkart.com","https://github.com")


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        loadUrl(url[0]) //by default.. first index
        mBinding.btnSendData.setOnClickListener {
           loadUrl(url = urls.random())
        }
       
    }

    private fun loadUrl(url:String){
        mBinding.webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
    
}

i am loading random url in to my webview one by one but i want to store the state so that i cannot load everytime if url and their any endpoint is already been loaded before then it should redirect to that state not load from scratch...

I think what you want is
 if (mBinding.webView.canGoBack()) {
       mBinding.webView.goBack()
} 

in your setOnClickListener()

no i just want to save the state i am laoding multiple url in my webview on button click so i want if url is already been loaded before then it should not load again from scratch it should redirect to my previous state.
